# Why my form isn't submitting ? using event in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for why my form isn't submitting with that code :

```
$("#my_form").on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!myCondition) {
        if (anotherCondition === true) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $('#modal').modal('show');
            $("#btn_valid").on('click', function(e) {
                return true;
            });       
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

The `modale` (who was present in the DOM) is showing but then if I hit the `#btn_valid` the form is not submitted and the modal stay on screen.

If I remove the `e.preventDefault`, the process is not stopped, meaning that the modale is showing and right after the form is submitting without pressing the button on the modale.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: You told it to not submit the form by using `preventDefault().` Returning true from your modal in no way says "now submit the form."

Comment: I do agree with you, but if i remove the preventDefault, the flow just continues, the modale is shown and just after without clicking on the button to confirm in the modale, the form is submitted.

Comment: This is meant to be "help to help yourself": Try to find out from which function "return true" will return and you will know that it will never do what you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var submitForm = false;
    $('#my_form').submit(function(e) {
        if (!submitForm) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#modal').modal('show');
        }
    });

    $("#btn_valid").on('click', function(e) {
        submitForm = true;
        $('#my_form').submit();
    });
});
```

You will see that once you click your button in the modal it will set `submitForm` to true and when you enter the form submit callback handler you will fall through the if statement, finally submitting the form as usual.